# Necessary theory to understand differentiable function approximation by lipschitz continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions

In Kolmogorov & Fomin's real analysis book specifically the section on convergence, open and closed sets in metric spaces, there is the following problem, which part a) asks to prove

The set of all functions on $[a,b]$ satisfying a Lipschitz condition of order $1$ (for some fixed constant $K$), denoted $M_K$ is 1) closed and 2) coincides with the closure of the set, denoted $D_K$, of all continuously differentiable functions on $[a,b]$ with first derivative bounded in absolute value by $K$ on all of $[a,b]$. (We are working in the space $C_{[a,b]}$ with metric $\max_{t\in [a,b]} |x(t)-y(t)|$)

After success with 1), I got stuck on 2) after proving that $cl(D_K)\subset M_K$, I failed to obtain the other set inclusion. After looking online for some suggestions, I noticed a lot of solutions used mollifiers and convolutions and sometimes mentioned a handful of higher spaces.

From what I recall, it's a matter of extending a given $K$-Lipschitz function $f$ to all the real line, so that it is $K$-Lipschitz on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Then you approximate the extension with a sequence obtained by convolutions with a mollifier and the extension. I understand that a mollifier is a smooth function that has compact support (identically zero outside a compact domain), has an integral over the whole real line equal to $1$ and satisfies a certain limit property with the dirac delta function, but I am not very familiar with the theory of distributions or generalized functions. I understand how to proceed with the extension of the original function but it is not apparent to me on how to show the convergence, and that the smoothness of the mollifier alone implies the smoothness of the sequence obtained by convolutions and hence satisfies the bounded condition on the first derivative. Am just I missing a lot of theory here?

Could someone explain these points or direct me towards some references so that I can learn them myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $M$ iff there is a constant $A$ and $g \in L^{\infty}[a,b]$ with $\|g\|_{\infty} \le M$ such that
$$
                         f(x) = A+\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt.
$$
Can you show that $\{ f \in C[a,b] : |f| \le M \}\subset L^1$ is dense in $\{ f \in L^{\infty}[a,b] : \|f\|_{\infty} \le M \}\subset L^1$ in the $L^1$ norm? If you can, then you should be able to show what you want.

Comment: I am familiar with the space $L_1$ and think I could prove that after some work and then get the result Im looking for. However, what is $L^\infty$ exactly? i cant seem to find the space in my books and I'd like to prove the iff related to Lipzschitz continuity you gave. Thank you for the nice answer.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 : $L^{\infty}$ consists of measurable functions that you can change on a set of measure $0$ in order to obtain a bounded function, and the norm is $\|f\|_{\infty} = \inf \{ C : |f(x)| \le C a.e. \}$. For $g \in L^{\infty}$, you have $|\int_{x}^{y}g(t)dt| \le \|g\|_{\infty}|x-y|$.

Comment: ah thank you. With that in mind one direction of the iff is obvious to me (if $f$ can be represented with such a $g \in L^\infty$ then $f$ is lipschitz continuous) but i don't see how to show the converse yet. How should I go about picking $g$ given a lipschitz continuous function $f$?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 : A Lipschitz continuous function $f$ is absolutely continuous, which means it's the integral of its derivative; and the derivative is bounded by the Lipschitz constant wherever it exists. Have you learned about absolutely continuous functions?

Comment: not quite. This question appears to be in the wrong section cuz it requires a bunch of material I haven't i studied thoroughly yet or its just assuming i would know this. I remember seeing the definition of absolute continuity in one of my books though so Ill study it now. Any other related topics you suggest for understanding problems like this?

Comment: ah i see it's Lebesgue's FTC, i'll have to do some review. Thank you very much.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 : You're welcome.